# Setting Custom Columns In Parse Is Nil

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I am trying to register for push notifications with parse using custom column names, such as Advances and Tours. Whenever I set them, they are nil in the Parse Data Browser online and I cannot send any pushes to those devices.

In didFinishLaunch:

```
[Parse setApplicationId:@"APP_ID"
              clientKey:@"CLIENT_KEY"];
[application registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge|
```

In didRegister:

```
PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
[currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

Once the user has signed in register them to their appropriate advances and tours:

```
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    NSMutableArray *advances = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *advanceId in [data objectForKey:@"advances"]) {
        [advances addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bs%@", advanceId]];
    }
    NSMutableArray *tours = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    for (NSString *tourId in [data objectForKey:@"tours"]) {
        [tours addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"bs%@", tourId]];
    }
    [currentInstallation setValue:advances forKey:@"advances"];
    [currentInstallation setValue:tours forKey:@"tours"];
    [currentInstallation setValue:[data objectForKey:@"uid"] forKey:@"uid"];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

In the data browser:

[image]

That goes for tours and uid, although it still creates the device. Any idea why this is happening?

## Update

After further research I found its: (Parse error 111.) The operation couldn't be completed

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to add an array of objects to an attribute.  Parse has specific syntax for this case.  Take a look at the docs for "Updating Objects" where it shows how to update arrays: https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-updating/iOS

Arrays

To help with storing array data, there are three operations that can be used to atomically change an array field:

- addObject:forKey: and addObjectsFromArray:forKey: append the given
  objects to the end of an array field.
- addUniqueObject:forKey: and addUniqueObjectsFromArray:forKey: add
  only the given objects which aren't already contained in an array
  field to that field. The position of the insert is not guaranteed.
- removeObject:forKey: and removeObjectsInArray:forKey: remove all
  instances of each given object from an array field.